# Copying files from a shared folder to a local folder in javaservlet

Tags: java, servlets, copying, shared-directory

Im developing a servlet, and I have to copy a file (*.doc) from a shared folder in other computer to my servlet webapp space, but I can't. The trouble is not writing on my Apache Server, instead of, Im expecting troubles copying the file from the remote folder (shared folder in a LAN). Any suggest or idea?

```
File inFile = new File( "\\\\192.168.2.103\\CompartidaMatias\\tablaEstudios.txt");
        out.println("<p> AbsolutePath --> " + inFile.getAbsolutePath() + "</p>");
        out.println("<p> Path --> " + inFile.getPath() + "</p>");
        out.println("<p> Nombre --> " + inFile.getName() + "</p>");
        out.println("<p> WEBAPP_ROOT --> " + WEBAPP_ROOT + "</p>");



        File outFile = new File(WEBAPP_ROOT + "mydoc3a.txt");

        if (inFile.exists())
            out.println("<p>FILE FOUND</p>");
        else
            out.println("<p>FILE NOT FOUND</p>");
```

I get always FILE NOT FOUND :(
Thanks for your time buddies!! I hope it could be solved, but I have spent all my ideas. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not how `java.io.File` works. It works on the local disk file system only, not on network resources.

Your best bet is to let your operating system platform create a local mapping (kind of a virtual disk) pointing to the network resource and, given you're on Windows, assign it a disk letter as well. Here's a [Microsoft Windows 7 guide on the subject](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive):

[image]

You just have to map `\\192.168.2.103` to e.g. `Z:\`. Once done that, you should be able to locate the file as follows:

```
new File("Z:/CompartidaMatias/tablaEstudios.txt");
```

*(note that `/` works as good as `\\` and saves you from effort of escaping them)*

Note that this problem has completely nothing to do with servlets. It's just a basic Java problem. You'd have exactly the same problem when executing this in a plain Java application with a `main()` method (which by the way allows for so much faster and easier testing than a servlet). Keep this in mind for your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
URL url = new URL( "file:///192.168.2.103//CompartidaMatias//tablaEstudios.txt" );
File inFile = new File( url.getFile() );
```

Comment: but not working :( I get wrong path :( Remember Im triying to do this from a servlet running in Apache, and maybe I cant get access to windows filesystem or I don't know. Today is a sad Friday for mi :( I'm just kidding!! :P Ain't not sad Fridays!! :)
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm running it from 2 windows pc's.

Comment: Go to start > run and type the url and hit enter. Does the file open? If so then you will likely need to start the Apache (Tomcat?) service with a user account that has access to the CompartidaMatias share. The user will also need access in NTFS file permissions. If not then the file may not actually exist or the share may not exist.

Comment: I think that's the trouble. If I execute the "query" like you told me I can open the file, but now I have no idea about giving permision to Tomcat to access that machine. I'm using the same user both for Tomcat and Windows. Any help??
Thanks a lot :D

Comment: If you are using the same user it is not a permission issue. Contrary to the answer below a URI is perfectly valid and has been since 1.4, see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)