# JAVA How do I retrieve a file from another computer using only it's IP Address on same network

Tags: java, path, copy, ip, transfer

I need to retrieve or copy a certain image file from the desktop of another computer on my network, to my own desktop.

```
//using the other pc's ip address, 192.168.10.2

String source = "\\\\192.168.10.2\\C$\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\1.png";
String target = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\1.png"

Files.copy(Paths.get(source),Paths.get(target),
StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Although there was no error message, nothing was copied over. I've ensured that the image file is on the other computer's desktop.

However, the code is working fine when I replace the ip address with my own ip address.

Comment: try it from the command line and see if that works.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13898378/2310289

Comment: for coping file over network ... its parent folder should be shared and have access rights to your IP to read it ..